# C changing a bit of uint32_t not working

Tags: c, sign, bit, uint32-t

I got

```
uint32_t bits = 0;

bits |= 1<< 31;
bits |= 1<< 15;
bits |= 1<< 14;
bits |= 1<< 13;
```

which gives me 10000000000000001110000000000000

and in another function I do `*(bits) |= 0 << 15;` but it doesn't do anything, it should change the 16th 1 to a 0, so the following should come: 10000000000000000110000000000000

any help?

Comment: `0 << 15` is `0`. No matter how many times you shift `0` to the left or right, you always end up with `0`.

Comment: Is the dereferencing in `*(bits) |= 0 << 15;` supposed to be there? Is the second `bits` not of type `uint32_t`? Reading through the question and answers this inconsistency seems a bit confusing although irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to change a bit to 0 is to `and` the negation, e.g.

```
bits &= ~(1 << 15);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do:

```
bits &= ~(1 << 15)
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearing a bit is done by AND-ing with the complement, i.e.:

```
*(bits) &= ~(1 << 15);
```

`(1 << 15)` produces a number with bit 15 set to `1`:

```
00000000000000001000000000000000
```

then the bitwise NOT operator inverts this and produces a number that is all ones except bit 15:

```
11111111111111110111111111111111
```

When you AND this number to the original one, the bit in position 15 is cleared:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
               &
11111111111111110111111111111111
================================
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

where X marks the original bits.